# InjectMocks couple of times

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

I have this piece of code -

```
@Component
public class ServiceA {

    @Autowired
    private ServiceB serviceB;

    public void someMethod() {
    for(Item item : items)
         serviceB.foo(item);
    }
}

@Component
public class ServiceB {

    @Autowired
    private ServiceC serviceC;

    public void foo(Item item) {
    if(item.boolean())
      serviceC.metA();
    else
      serviceC.metB()
    }
}
```

in addition, I have a test class -

```
public serviceATest {


    @Spy
    @InjectMocks
    private ServiceA serviceA;

    @Spy
    @InjectMocks
    private ServiceB serviceB; 

    @Mock
    private ServiceC serviceC;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public generalTest() {
    serviceA.someMethod();
    }
}
```

In this case - ServiceB is null in ServiceA, and ServiceC is not null in ServiceB.

I want that ServiceB will be not null in ServiceA and keep ServiceC not null in ServiceB.

what can I do in order to make it work?

Comment: You're missing the point of mocking. ServiceA doesn't depend on ServiceC. It only depends on ServiceB. So when you test ServiceA, the only thing that you need to mock is ServiceB. Once you've mocked ServiceB, ServiceC is irrelevant: a mock is a fake object, not doing anything. You'll mock SeviceC and inject it in ServiceB when you'll write the unit test of ServiceB.

Comment: @JBNizet - you're totally right. but what can I do in my case when I call serviceB.foo()? I have a few options and it depends on other things..

Comment: @JBNizet - I edit the question to make it clearer. thks

Comment: Apparently, the only thing that ServiceA.someMethod() is supposed to do is to call ServiceB.foo(). That's what its contract seems to be. So, test that the contract is respected. Call serviceA.someMethod(), and verify that the mock ServiceB.foo() method has been called. Of course, it begs the question: "should I really test that?".

Comment: You've now changed the method. Now apparently the contract is that it should call ServiceB.foo() with every item of items. So, test that contract: fill items with 2 or 3 values, call serviceA.someMethod(), and test that the mock serviceB.foo() has been called with every item. I'm still not sure it deserves being tested, but that's your choice.

Comment: @Dvir This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you ***actually*** trying to test?

Comment: @Dvir - Can you let us know, what you ended up doing.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you need to mock the call of `ServiceC` defined in class `ServiceB` and same for other case

Test code snippet

```
@Test
public generalTest1() {
Mockito.when(serviceC.metA()).thenReturn(<Whatever is the return type of foo()>);
Mockito.when(serviceC.metB()).thenReturn(<Whatever is the return type of foo()>);
serviceB.foo();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought about it already - but the problem is that I have a switch-case (where I wrote an if statement) - and I want to save all the "when" and use Mock instead. I'll use this as a last resort.

Comment: btw - how are u making the Mock annotations in the test? does ServiceB is still a Spy?

Answer (score 0):

For the example you have provided, service A method does not really contain any business logic to test for apart from calling  serviceB method. And since the whole point of unit testing is to test the business logic of a particular class/method there is no point of testing this method as there is no business logic to test.

If we consider about the mocking you have provided, when unit testing a class A you should mock all those classes that are referred in class A. In your case to test service A, serviceB is required to be mocked as it is being referred in class A DIRECTLY. But since service C is nowhere referred in A there is no need to mock that. 
Now when testing a method, we mock the results of all the methods being called inside it. The objective is again to test whether the business logic of Method is working as expected.

The class under test is annotated with ‘InjectMocks’ ( service A in your case)
@Mock for objects being referred by service A ( serviceB’s object ) 
Later , methods can be mocked using Mockito.mock method.